# Unable to View/Edit Document Properties

Tags: 2013, document, document-set

I have a document set that consists of multiple documents.  Each document has a unique content type.
If I create a document set, I can `view` and `edit` properties for all except one of the documents on the **Document Set Welcome Page**.

In the case of that one document, the `view/edit` properties buttons are **disabled** (they are enabled for the other documents).  If I edit the welcome page, the `view/edit` properties buttons for that one document become enabled.  If I stop editing the page, the `view/edit` properties buttons for that one document become disabled.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, please verify the following things:

1. Check if the user has permissions to edit this document.
2. Use the content type with issue to create a new document in this document set, then check if the issue still exists.
3. Change the content type of this document with issue, then check the issue again.